# Solaris 11.3 npm install EPROTOTYPE error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am using node.js 0.12.2 (tried both x86/x64) and npm 2.7.4 on Solaris 11.3 to code a node.js native binding for a library. The node.js and npm are downloaded from the nodejs.org site.

When I try to install the "node-gyp" package (command line: sudo npm install -g for building the native binding, I got the following error message on screen:

```
npm ERR! SunOS 5.11
npm ERR! argv "/opt/Node/bin/node" "/opt/Node/bin/npm" "install" "node-gyp"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code EPROTOTYPE
npm ERR! errno EPROTOTYPE
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! connect EPROTOTYPE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /export/home/wto/work/npm-debug.log
```

I do have the Solaris 11.3 box set up with static IP address and will try reset the installation by removing the .npmrc directory under my profile.

Here is also the detailed logs:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/opt/Node/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/opt/Node/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'node-gyp' ]
2 info using npm@2.7.4
3 info using node@v0.12.2
4 verbose node symlink /opt/Node/bin/node
5 silly cache add args [ 'node-gyp', null ]
6 verbose cache add spec node-gyp
7 silly cache add parsed spec { raw: 'node-gyp',
7 silly cache add   scope: null,
7 silly cache add   name: 'node-gyp',
7 silly cache add   rawSpec: '',
7 silly cache add   spec: '*',
7 silly cache add   type: 'range' }
8 verbose addNamed node-gyp@*
9 silly addNamed semver.valid null
10 silly addNamed semver.validRange *
11 silly addNameRange { name: 'node-gyp', range: '*', hasData: false }
12 silly mapToRegistry name node-gyp
13 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
14 silly mapToRegistry registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
15 silly mapToRegistry uri http://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp
16 verbose addNameRange registry:http://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp not in flight; fetching
17 verbose request uri http://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp
18 verbose request no auth needed
19 info attempt registry request try #1 at 2:13:54 PM
20 verbose request id 5f84afed96726fed
21 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp
22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect EPROTOTYPE
23 info attempt registry request try #2 at 2:14:04 PM
24 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp
25 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect EPROTOTYPE
26 info attempt registry request try #3 at 2:15:04 PM
27 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp
28 verbose stack Error: connect EPROTOTYPE
28 verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
28 verbose stack     at connect (net.js:842:19)
28 verbose stack     at net.js:945:9
28 verbose stack     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback (dns.js:81:16)
28 verbose stack     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:99:10)
29 verbose cwd /export/home/wto/work
30 error SunOS 5.11
31 error argv "/opt/Node/bin/node" "/opt/Node/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "node-gyp"
32 error node v0.12.2
33 error npm  v2.7.4
34 error code EPROTOTYPE
35 error errno EPROTOTYPE
36 error syscall connect
37 error connect EPROTOTYPE
38 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
38 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
39 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Thanks for all assistance.

Comment: I ended up using a custom build from Peter Tribble instead to make this work.